# I can't take value from Hashmap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I can't to take value from dataF when I use map.put that say error.if I replace map.put("Nos",dataF); to map.put("Nos",dataF[arrLength]) It's work but It's return [Ljava.lang.string;@b1f37df0

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String[]>> ArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String[]>>();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String[] dataF = intent.getStringArrayExtra("Money");

    ListView list1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    int arrLength = dataF.length;

    for(int i=0;i<arrLength;i++)
    {
    HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    map.put("Nos", dataF[arrLength]);   //  << error 
    ArrList.add(map);          // << error
    }
    ListAdapter adapters = new SimpleAdapter(resultActivity.this,ArrList,
            R.layout.activity_column,
            new String[] {"Nos"},new int[] { R.id.textView1});
    list1.setAdapter(adapters);
```

Comment: Ignoring everything else, I can guarantee you that `dataF[arrLength]` isn't doing anything but throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try put `map.put("Nos", dataF[arrLength]);` as `HashMap<String, String[]>` but `dataF[arrLength]` is a one `String` and your `hashmap` need one `Array` of String.

you can change that to:

```
map.put("Nos", dataF);
```

if you solve this i think next line is solved too.

and with `dataF[arrLength]` you must get `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` because last index of your array is `dataF[arrLength - 1]`

**UPDATE**

with your say on comment i think you try show `hashMpa.getValue();` but your value is array of String so you need show one index of that like `hashMpa.getValue()[0];`

you need following for showing values:

```
String[] value = hashMap.getValue();

for ( int i = 0 ; i < value.lenght() ; i++)
        Log.d("index "+i , value[i]);
```

Comment: when I change same you(map.put("Nos", dataF);) It's show [Ljava.lang.string;@b1f37df0 not value

Comment: what is your mean about `It's show`? where you show that and how you do that?

Comment: in my listview show [Ljava.lang.string;@b1f37df0 same this picture http://upic.me/show/49911578

Comment: can you post that code, because i think you just show all array, you need show index of that

Comment: I will try update but It's not work for me.Now I try to remove[] from everwhere in HashMap and replace map.put("Nos", dataF[i]); It's work!!. Thank you very much for help and guide me ^^

Answer (score 0):

Update the code as below::

```
    HashMap<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    map.put("Nos", dataF);   //  Pass the Array instead String
    ArrList.add(map);
```

Comment: when I change same you It's show [Ljava.lang.string;@b1f37df0 not value

Comment: I guess you are trying to print the object instead the value.Use toString() method on it. @FlyzyDev